# Find matrix with 0 or 1 that in square gives matrix with of only ones.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, bilinear-operator

Еhis is a task on the topic "bilinear and quadratic forms".

Problem: For which number $n$ there exists a square matrix of order $n$ with elements 0, 1 such that its square is a matrix of only ones.

Well, when I tried find the solution, I came to fact that $n$ only can be 1.

Let $J_n$ be the square matrix of ones [(all entries are a one).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones)

I tried to find new basis where quadratic form with matrix $J_n$ where $J_n$ became diagonal matrix, but can't find $n$ linearly independent vectors for this basis. Because of this I suppose that $n$ only can be equal 1.

Also tried to make linear system of equations with $n^2$ rows and again came to a standstill.

Comment: No. E.g. $\pmatrix{0&1&0&1\\ 1&0&1&0\\ 1&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&1}^2=J_4$. The underlying field also matters. E.g. $J_3^2=J_3$ over $GF(2)$ but not over $\mathbb R$. Your question lacks details. Is your matrix real? Is it symmetric?

Comment: @user1551 This is full text of the problem. Just need to find $n$.

Comment: @user1551 I think only real.

Comment: @RobPratt I saw it, this question have same parts with my question, but nothing about condition only ones and zeros.

Comment: As RobPratt mentioned in a deleted comment, are you sure that you are asking about an $A$ such that $A^2=J_n$ rather than $A^TA=J_n$?

Comment: At first sight, and noticing that $J_n^2=nJ_n$, we can say that if some $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{C})$ satisfies $M^2=J_n$ then $M^4=nM^2$, and the minimum polynomial $\mu_M(X)$ divides $X^2(X^2-nI)$.
$M$ is similar to a triangular matrix having $k$ elements $\pm\sqrt{n}$ on its diagonal and $(n-k)$ zeroes.
Squaring this, we get that $J_n$ is similar to a triangular matrix having $k$ elements $n$ and $(n-k)$ zeroes on its diagonal.
Considering the trace of $J_n$ we get that $k=1$.
Does that lead somewhere?